# Match Phone number from two data extensions and update status field in master Data extension

Tags: sql, automation, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I have Opt-out Data extension which contains phone number, Operation as Status of the subscriber is 'InActive' , I would like to update status of those phone number as 'False' in Master DE.

Query executed successfully but, status of those phonenumbers not updated in Master DE.

I built below query:

```sql
SELECT 
a.PHONE_NUMBER
, 'InActive' as OPERATION  
from Optin_Optout_History_Testing a
INNER JOIN Cust_List_Master_Testing b ON a.PHONE_NUMBER = b.PHONE_NUMBER
WHERE b.Status = 'False'
```

[image: Optout data extension]

[image: Master DE]

Comment: You are using `SELECT`.  You shouldn't expect any data to change.  To affect existing data, you should use `UPDATE`.

Comment: Salesforce marketing cloud wont allow UPDATE statement, gives error "Select must be the first word of the query"

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [query](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query) tags.

Comment: Please update your question to include the data types of the fields in both DEs.

Comment: @ArifShaikh . . . In that case, you cannot change the data.  Perhaps you can create a view so you can query the tables with the information you want.